Issue with scan-inline barcode reader on iOS
I'm creating a power app to scan tickets at the entrance to an event. I've added the barcode scanner object to my app and I set the scan mode to inline as I'd like other elements of my UI to be visible during scanning.
In the powerapps studio it says that inline scanning is only available on mobile apps (as expected) but when I save and publish my app, open it on my iphone in the native app, it still says this same message - see screenshot.
I've restarted the app and ensured it's on the latest update (version 3.24091.12). I tried scan mode auto and it works as expected but scan inline doesn't seem to be working.
I'd appreciate any help/thoughts. Thanks.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. The image you posted was absolutely unnecessary. The textual message is very clear, and did not need a graphical display. Post code, data and errors as text, where they are usable and searchable. Images should be used ONLY when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem, such as graphics or HTML rendering problems. And if you DO need to post an image for those reasons, at least have the common courtesy to crop them to the smallest size possible.

Thank you for taking the time to ignore my question

I clearly didn't ignore your question. I obviously paid enough attention that I noticed the blatant disregard for the norms here when you posted the absolutely useless, gigantic images. I also took the time to try to educate you on how to post here properly, including putting effort into finding you written best practices for the use of mages here. The civil response to someone who has volunteered their time to teach you something is to say "Thank you". You're welcome.

You say you haven't ignored my question but I haven't seen an answer from you. This entire site is meant to be for people helping each other out rather than just plain criticism. If you don't know the answer, there was no need for you to comment on what was me just trying to be helpful. I can see you've downvoted 5x as many posts as you've upvoted so clearly you have a habit for just criticising people who are trying to learn.

I commented because you need to learn about proper use of images here. If you had posted properly without the images, I wouldn't have needed to comment at all. FYI, since you seem to be very unaware of how this site works, users do most of the moderation and curation to keep the site clean and useful. Part of that task is attempting to educate newer (and sometimes older) users about how the site works. Downvoting is proper and expected - it's part of how the site is designed to work. It's actually considered a good thing when you downvote bad questions. You should go back and read the [help].

And see? Once again, I've spent considerable effort trying to educate you on how this site works. And while you're reading those [help] pages, make sure that you read the Code of Conduct (CoC) - you're getting very close to starting personal insults aimed at me, and that is a flaggable violation here. (Also note that even though you've been told that the images are improper because they are unnecessary, you haven't bothered to [edit] your post to remove them yet.)

I have encountered the same issue and had trouble finding the correct answer so thought I would drop it here for the next person:
The inline scanning only works as part of a device optimized app. You need to enable your app to be device optimized by going to Settings->Updates->Preview and turning on the Optimize for devices toggle.
You then need to ensure that everything on the screen is a device optimized control. This can be done by ensuring that the Device optimized filter is applied whenever you add a new control

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
